# What parts of an object are stored when it's saved into a session variable

Tags: asp.net, performance, session, memory

I have some code I've inherited that stores multiple complex objects into session variables.  The base class for the objects contain several public properties and quite a lot of public static methods. My concern is what this is doing on memory allocation since the only parts that matter are the properties.  Does the entire instance of the object get stored, methods/code and all? If not, what declaration types do?